# How to assign a String to a variable in C

Tags: c, string, char

I create an `Entity` object:

```
#ifndef ENTITY_H  
#define ENTITY_H  

struct MyEntityObject {  
    char  _entityAuthor;
};  

#endif // ENTITY_H
```

Then I try to set it up and use it:

```
struct MyEntityObject myEntityObject;  

/* MyEntityObject data specification */  
strcpy(myEntityObject . _entityAuthor, "Shakespear");
```

I get this error:

```
main.cpp:37: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]  
      myEntityObject . _entityAuthor = "Shakespear";  
                             ^
```

What is going on here? What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
char _entityAuthor;
```

...declares a `char` variable.

What you need is a ***pointer to `char`*** (`char *`) variable:

```
char *_entityAuthor;
```

---

You will also need to ***allocate memory*** with [**`malloc()`**](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) before using `strcpy()`.

[**Here is a tutorial.**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Your struct field is only a single `char`

```
struct MyEntityObject {  
    char  _entityAuthor;  
};
```

Trying changing it to either  a `char *` that you dynamically allocate memory to or a `char` array if you can make solid assumptions about the size of the string.

Comment: Just to clarify the meaning of `dynamically allocate` above, if the OP uses a `char *` for the field, then the call to strcpy will crash. `strdup` will allocate the memory for the field, if `malloc` hasn't been called.